# Proper Typescript type for a reused screen in react-navigation v5

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

For most of the cases, I follow a simple pattern to type any screen under react-navigation v5:

```
// Params definition
type RouteParamsList = {
    Screen1: {
        paramA: number
    }
    Screen2: undefined
}

// Screen1

type Props = StackScreenProps<RouteParamsList, 'Screen1'>

export const Screen1: React.FC<Props> = ...
```

That works perfectly.

I can't figure out the proper types for a case when I'd want to reuse the `Screen1` for different navigators though:

```
// Params definition
type RouteParamsListShop = {
    Screen1: {
        paramA: number
    }
    Screen2: undefined
    Screen3: undefined
}

type RouteParamsListFeatures = {
    Screen1: {
        paramA: number
    }
    Screen4: undefined
}

// Screen1

type Props = StackScreenProps<RouteParamsListShop, 'Screen1'> | StackScreenProps<RouteParamsListFeatures, 'Screen1'> // Tried this

export const Screen1: React.FC<Props> = ...
```

As I commented, I tried to have a union type covering both cases. It allows to get the parameters from the route properly, but `navigate` method breaks:

`This expression is not callable. Each member of the union type '/* Route info here */' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.ts(2349)`

Is there a way to properly type it, or I rather have to change the structure of my navigation to make the screen only part of one route? (alternatively, create 2 wrappers for different navigation).

Comment: I assume that the interfaces for `Screen1` in `Shop` differ from `Screen1` in `Features`?

Comment: @MaltePeters no, they're identical, except the navigators they belong to

Answer (score 0):

As long as the two interfaces are equal, you could do something like this:

```
interface Screen1Params {
  paramA: number;
}

type RouteParamsListShop = {
    Screen1: Screen1Params;
    Screen2: undefined;
    Screen3: undefined;
}

type RouteParamsListFeatures = {
    Screen1: Screen1Params;
    Screen4: undefined;
}

...

type Props = StackScreenProps<RouteParamsListShop, 'Screen1'>;
```

I didn't try, but the Union should also work now, since the two types should be equal:

```
type Props = StackScreenProps<RouteParamsListShop, 'Screen1'> | StackScreenProps<RouteParamsListFeatures, 'Screen1'>
```

Comment: this code you used in the answer gives the same error I experience

Comment: if you're curious, feel free to try it by yourself. I'll post the answer I came with later

Answer (score 0):

There's a more fundamental issue at play here than just typing the union properly.  If our `navigation` prop is for `RouteParamsListShop` then we can navigate to `Screen2`.  If our `navigation` prop is for `RouteParamsListFeatures` then we can't because `Screen2` isn't defined on that stack.  So there's an inherent incompatibility.

Are you only ever trying to navigate from `Screen1` to another screen which is also declared on both?  If so, we can type that.  If not, you have a design problem.

Rather than a union, what you want is a shared subset that includes both the target screen and the current screen.  We can use some helper types to make this easier.

```
type SharedKeys = keyof RouteParamsListShop & keyof RouteParamsListFeatures

// we Pick from both instead of just one in case the params are different
type SharedParams = Pick<RouteParamsListShop, SharedKeys> & Pick<RouteParamsListFeatures, SharedKeys>

type Props = StackScreenProps<SharedParams, 'Screen1'>
```

This allows you to call `navigation.navigate` -- but only if navigating to a screen which is defined in both stack types.  In you example there are no screens left that we can navigate to, but presumably there will be available navigation targets in your real world case.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/vWkglW)

Comment: is it possible to get the types right based off a shared param. For example referenced in this issue: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10482